# legends do not stay in place when resizing linked graphs in dygraphs

Tags: css, position, legend, dygraphs

After I synchronize graphs in dygraphs, the legends do not stay in place when I zoom/unzoom/reset.

I have initialized the graphs as such :

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("demodiv"),
    data.slice(50),
    options
);

g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("demodiv2"),
    data,
    options
);
```

The legends style is modified through `jQuery` :

```
$("#container .dygraph-legend").css("left", "50px");
$("#container .dygraph-legend").css("width", "150px");
```

and, finally, I synchronize like this :

```
Dygraph.synchronize([g, g2], {
  selection: true,
  zoom: true,
  range: false
});
```

Then, playing around with zooming, unzooming and reset on both graphs, the legends move around.

I have created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chapo/6pkuycv5/6/) to show the issue (code for the graphs is at line 618).

Snippet for the same:

How to make them keep their initial position even when zooming etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't

You should **not** change the `Dygraph` element styles with `jQuery`. Since `Dygraph` will continuously change the styles, your `jQuery` styles will be no longer effective.

#### Option

Dygraph provides an option to specify another DOM element to be the legend. It means, you can put your legend contents into another div or any other DOM element  you want.

The option is called `labelsDiv`. Read more [here](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#labelsDiv)

#### Solution

Since we can now use another `DOM` element as our legend / label content. let's change the DOM structure a bit:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="demodiv"></div>
  <div id="legend"></div>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <div id="demodiv2"></div>
    <div id="legend2"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that we have now two different container for two different Dygraph charts. We wrapped them with container to apply style `position: relative;` on containers and to put `position: absolute;` on the `#legend` and `#legend2`. Lets have a look at the CSS now.

```
#container, #container2 {
  position: relative;
}

#legend, #legend2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* set accordingly */
  left: 0; /* set accordingly */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px; /* set accordingly */
  background-color: #fff; /* set accordingly */
}
```

Now your Script, we are going to provide the `labelsDiv` option and specify our target div elements:

```
var data = [ ... ] // your data here;

g = new Dygraph( document.getElementById("demodiv"), data.slice(50), {
    customBars: true,
    labels: ["date", "a", "b", "c"],
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('legend'),
});

g2 = new Dygraph( document.getElementById("demodiv2"), data, {
    customBars: true,
    labels: ["date", "a", "b", "c"],   
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('legend2'),
});

Dygraph.synchronize([g, g2], {
    selection: true,
    zoom: true,
    range: false
});
```

#### Snippet

I tried a lot to create a snippet here so that the result is visible here with one click, but having error. So here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Towkir/41Lat7px/1/)

Comment: Can't get the fiddle to load but your code looks great. Will give it a try tomorrow and validate the answer. Thanks for the very detailed answer.

Comment: yes I validated your answer. Thank you for taking the time.